# /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/bin/catalina.sh: line 467: /opt/jdk-13.0.1/bin/java: No such file or directory on dockers, OS centos 8 minimal

Tags: java, oracle, docker, tomcat9, centos8

I want to create a docker image with `tomcat 9` with Oracle `JDK 13` to deploy an application. Having error

> /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.29/bin/catalina.sh`:Error line 467: /opt/jdk-13.0.1/bin/java: No such file or directory on dockers, OS centos 8 minimal.

Comment: correct the formatting

Answer (score 0):

issue has been resolved. Removed the traces of JRE from env variables as well as found a blank space in java path.